# php Echo the user details by unique value

Tags: php, mysql

I am Trying this in my website, **As When the user Type the LOAN ID, The Details of that user will Echo in the input field**.

Consider My Database Has:

```
Id     name     email       country      zip     Phone        Loanid
1     kalyan   xxxx@yy.com  California  77777    999999       ABCDEF
```

**So In my case when the user Input Loanid It should Echo All The Field of that Customer.**

My Code: I am Getting Empty Result By This:

```
<form action="?p=show" method="post" name="details">
    <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">TYPE YOUR LOAN ID:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="code" required="" placeholder="Your Name"
                            data-bv-notempty="true"
                            data-bv-notempty-message="The username is required and cannot be empty"

                            data-bv-stringlength="true"
                            data-bv-stringlength-min="6"
                            data-bv-stringlength-max="30"
                            data-bv-stringlength-message="The username must be more than 6 and less than 30 characters long"

                            data-bv-regexp="true"
                            data-bv-regexp-regexp="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"
                            data-bv-regexp-message="The username can only consist of alphabetical and number"

                            data-bv-different="true"
                            data-bv-different-field="password"
                            data-bv-different-message="The username and password cannot be the same as each other" />

                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" id="myregister" class="btn btn-default">SHOW LOAN APPLICATION</button>
                </div>

</form>




<?php

if($_REQUEST['t']=="show"){
$code=$_REQUEST['code'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT firstname, lastname, mobileno FROM loanapp WHERE code='$code'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

echo $row['firstname'].'<br>';
echo $row['lastname'].'<br>';
echo $row['mobileno'].'<br>';


}

}
?>
```

So I need Output Should be like This

Output should be:

```
                                                          LoanId: ABCDEF

Firstname: kalyan                   E-mail: xxxx@yy.com

Country:   California               zipcode: 77777

Phone:    999999

                           SUBMIT
```

Please Help By Right Solution Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So, the values are being echo'd correctly, you're looking to format it the way you showed it as output? In an HTML table? Is that what this question is about?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am not geeting result, it when i click SHOW APPLICATION it just shows Empty page.

Comment: `if($_REQUEST['t']=="show")` the "t" should be a "p" since you're  doing `?p` in action.

Comment: You also don't have a "code" column but you do have "Loanid". You have answers below with solutions in both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will have a go. 
1. Your first mistake is `if($_REQUEST['t']=="show")` insteand of `if($_REQUEST['p']=="show")`. Notice you use 't' instead of 'p' as a parameter for `$_REQUEST[]`.

2. Your `WHERE` clause should read `WHERE loanid =` isted of 'code'. You do not have 'code' in the table you provided.
3. An alternative: You could use `$code = $_POST['code']` instead.
   Hopefully, this helps you.
4. Your SQL does calls values that does not exist in your table such as 'firstname', lastname, etc. To be safe, since you want everything, just do:

`'SELECT * from table where loanid = '.$code`

Comment: if it worked, mark my answer as the solution for future users. And vote me up :)

Comment: i marked your answer, sorry i dont have reputation to vote, in future i gona do that, thanks buddy, that works.

Answer (score 0):

use $_GET['p'] and $_POST['code']
hope it helps.
http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.request.php

```
<?php

if($_GET['p']=="show"){
$code=$_POST['code'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT name, email, country, zip, Phone, LoanId FROM loanapp WHERE code='$code'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

echo "<p>LoanId: $row['LoanId']</p>";
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><td>Firstname: $row['firstname']</td><td>Email: $row['email']</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Country: $row['country']</td><td>Zip: $row['zip']</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Phone $row['phone']</td></tr>";
echo "</table>";

}

}
?>
```